# How to call a PostgreSQL function in a Sequelize model with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently using the Sequelize ORM with NodeJS and Typescript and a PostgreSQL database. I've created a function `func_items()` which returns specific columns from different tables which I would like to use in a Sequelize model, but when I try to query the database, I get the following error:

`relation "func_items()" does not exist.`

This is my model:

```
import { DataTypes, Optional, ModelDefined, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import connect from '../../utils/database';
import { Item } from '../interface/Item';

const sequelize = connect();

export type ItemCreationAttributes = Required<Item>;

const ItemModel: ModelDefined<Item, ItemCreationAttributes> = sequelize.define(
    'item',
    {
        item_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        date_added: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        tableName: 'func_items()',
        timestamps: false,
    }
)

export default ItemModel;
```

Has anyone experienced this issue or can assist me in resolving it?